# How to Automatically update expiry date from month in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have to update the expiry date by counting from the month. Please guide me. While saving data expiry date is working fine. But I don't understand how to update it.

**My Controller Code For Save Data**

```
public function pay_success(Request $request){


    $input = $request->all();
    date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
    $input['months'] = $request->months;       
    $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($input['months']);
    $input['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']); 


    $user = User::create($input);


    //Send Email
    $email = $input['email'];
    $messageData = ['email' =>$input['email'],'name' =>$input['name'],'package' =>$input['package'],'months' =>$input['months'],'amount' =>$input['amount'],'expiry_date' =>$input['expiry_date']];
    Mail::send('emails.mail',$messageData,function($message) use($email){
        $message->to($email)->subject('Registration with AddSpy');
    });


    $arr = array('msg' => 'Payment successful.', 'status' => true);

    return Response()->json($arr);    
}
```

**My Update Code is**

```
public function update(Request $request) {

        date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
        $months = $request->months; 
        $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($months);  
        $request['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;

        $data = ['id'=>$request->id, 'name'=>$request->name, 'phone'=>$request->phone, 'country'=>$request->country, 'state'=>$request->state,
                 'purpose'=>$request->purpose, 'package'=>$request->package, 'months'=>'$months', 'quantity'=>$request->quantity, 'amount'=>$request->amount,  'expiry_date'=>'$expiry_date'];
        DB::table('users')->where('id',$request->id)->update($data);


        return response()->json($data);
}
```

Anyone please suggest me a answer. I do changes in my code but It gives this message **"message": "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '$expiry_date' for column `addspy`.`users`.`expiry_date` at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `id` = 47, `name` = Ayush, `phone` = 6393611129, `country` = India, `state` = UP, `purpose` = parent, `package` = basic, `months` = $months, `quantity` = 1, `amount` = 4000, `expiry_date` = $expiry_date where `id` = 47)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",**

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: do u want to update status or update the expiry_date

Comment: I want to update the expiry from months count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending strings to the database (`'$months'` & `'$expiry_date'`). Simply removing the quotes should fix your problem.

i.e.

```
$data = [
    'id' => $request->id, 
    'name' => $request->name, 
    'phone' => $request->phone, 
    'country' => $request->country, 
    'state' => $request->state,
    'purpose' => $request->purpose, 
    'package' => $request->package, 
    'months' => $months, 
    'quantity' => $request->quantity, 
    'amount' => $request->amount,  
    'expiry_date' => $expiry_date,
];
```